# Solve for $x$ in the equation containing ${\lfloor{x}\rfloor}$ and $\{x\}$

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

> Calculate all possible values of $x$ satisfying,
>
> $$\frac{\lfloor{x}\rfloor}{\lfloor{x-2}\rfloor}-\frac{\lfloor{x-2}\rfloor}{\lfloor{x}\rfloor}=\frac{8\{x\}+12}{\lfloor{x}\rfloor
>  \lfloor{x-2}\rfloor}$$
>
> where $\{x\}$ stands for fractional part of $x$.

**My Attempt:**

$${\lfloor{x}\rfloor}^2-{\lfloor{x-2}\rfloor}^2={8\{x\}+12}$$

${\lfloor{x}\rfloor}^2-{\lfloor{x-2}\rfloor}^2$ is an integer, so ${8\{x\}+12}$ must also be an integer, i.e. $8\{x\}$ must be an integer.

As, $0\leq{\{x\}}\lt{1}$, Therefore the only integer values of $8\{x\}$ will be,

$$\{x\}=0 \implies 8\{x\}=0 \implies 8\{x\}+12=12$$

$$\{x\}=\frac{1}{2} \implies 8\{x\}=4 \implies 8\{x\}+12=16$$

$$\{x\}=\frac{1}{4} \implies 8\{x\}=2 \implies 8\{x\}+12=14$$

$$\{x\}=\frac{1}{8} \implies 8\{x\}=1 \implies 8\{x\}+12=13$$

On calculating , we get that $12$,$16$ can be expressed as,

$$16=5^2-3^2 \implies 5\leq{x}\lt 6$$

but $\{x\}=\frac{1}{2}, \therefore x=5+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{11}{2}$

$$12=4^2-2^2 \implies 4\leq{x}\lt 5 $$

but $\{x\}=0, \therefore x=4+0=4$

Therefore the only solution set is,

$$\bigg\{4,\frac{11}{2}\bigg\}$$

Is this the correct approach? I am afraid that I am missing some values.

Comment: Why can't $\{x\}=\frac 34$, say?

Comment: @lulu, Won't this form infinite cases then?

Comment: No...your argument shows that the denominator is $\in \{1,2,4,8\}$.  Of course the numerator must be less than the denominator.

Comment: Can I prove that $12,16$ are the only such pairs that can be expressed as a difference of squares of numbers off by 2?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your method...my remark just shows that you have to try a few more cases.  As the posted solutions show, there are ways to simplify the algebra to eliminate cases...but with problems like these it is usually a matter of efficiency.  Is it faster to try a few extra cases or to think it through carefully enough to eliminate as many bad cases as possible before searching?  Here, your method yields such a small number of test cases that I'd probably just go with that.

Comment: Your solution is correct i.e $x=4$ or $ x=5.5$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**hint**

Observe that

$$\lfloor x-2 \rfloor =\lfloor x\rfloor -2$$

the equation becomes

$$\lfloor x \rfloor=2\{x\}+4$$

Answer (score 1):

Decompose $x=n+f$. Then

$$\frac n{n-2}-\frac{n-2}n=\frac{8f+12}{n(n-2)}$$ or

$$n^2-(n-2)^2=8f+12$$

or

$$f=\frac{n-4}2.$$

The possible values for $n$ are $4$ and $5$ (so that $0\le f<1$).

Answer (score 0):

From Fatima's approach you should have something like $   (\lfloor x \rfloor-4)/2=\{x\}$. So the only solution to this $\lfloor x \rfloor=4$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor=5$, with $\{x\}=0$ and $\{x\}=1/2$, respectively.